# jslint error - #1 Expected '(end)' and instead saw '<!'

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, jslint

I am typing in a v simple example into sublime text.  I have the SublimeLinter and JSLint plugins installed, but am getting the following error:

```
#1 Expected '(end)' and instead saw '<!'.
```

The code is a simple HTML file, which may be my problem.  I don't know.

The code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If it is true that either linting plugin is causing this error what should I do?

Comment: It's happening at the very first two characters of your source.

Comment: HTML is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated by JSLint. By default, it runs on files with extensions `.js`, `.json`, `.html`, `.sass`, and `.less`. To prevent the error without disabling or removing JSLint, try removing HTML files from this list.

To do this, open `JSLint.sublime-settings`. Around line 35 you should see the following property.

`,"filename_filter": "(\\.js|\\.json|\\.html|\\.sass|\\.less|\\.html)$"`

Erase both `|\\.html` entries so that you're left with this.

`,"filename_filter": "(\\.js|\\.json|\\.sass|\\.less)$"`

Save your file. You may need to restart Sublime Text. Also note that you can still run JSLint on an HTML file using the following shortcut.

- <kbd>Control</kbd> + L